# Control M Email Notification shout when Job not ended OK

Tags: notifications, batch-processing, email-notifications, control-m

I've 50+ jobs in a control m folder.
For specific jobs, I want to update on do action like when job ended not ok, it should send email.

I can find the specific job using "Find" option.

But how to mass update the On-Do action for email notification when job ended not ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the **Find&Update** option apply the following:

First filter the cases to be modified in bulk mode. It could be all the Jobs in the Folder.

Then apply the update criteria, in this case, a **Notification** is added:

- **Add Notification**:

  - **Set When assign** *Not Ok*
  - **Set Urgency assign** *Urgent*
  - **Set Message assign** *"The Job %%JOBNAME Failed ..."*
  - **Set Destination assign** *the@mail.com"*
  - ...

For example:

[image]